# Adding BaseGameUtils as library (Google Play Game Services)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to add the BaseGameUtils lib to my poject and following the instructions on https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

and downloaded the BaseGameUtils on here https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

When I am trying to import the BaseGameUtils lib -Using Eclipse- (File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace)

Tried both "android-basic-sample-master" and "BaseGameUtils" folders selecting as root folder selection.
After finishing the import, project name is appears as "main". Not BaseGameUtils.

I tried that "main" project marked as "is library" and right click on my app folder then from the android selection on the left, added "main" project as a library and then applied it.

But I get the error when I tried to use GameHelper class; "GameHelper cannot be resolved to a type"

for example when trying this;

```
.
.
.
.
GameHelper mHelper;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        .          
        .       
            mHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);

            GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                    // handle sign-in succeess
                }
                @Override
                public void onSignInFailed() {
                    // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
                }

            };
            mHelper.setup(listener);
    }
```

I can't find any solution. Followed the instructions carefully, but still got the problem. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: did you ensure to add the library to your build path and did you confirm that its in your apk?

Comment: It is appears as main.jar in Android Dependencies folder in the java build path window @JoxTraex